# Adding percent sign in middle of a label while using scientific styling

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to put a y-label on my plot for titanium oxide, my label has to be like this: [image: Desired plot label]

How do I manage to keep the scientific styling while putting the percent sign, I have tried the following which doesnt seems to work

```
plt.ylabel('{0} %\n'.format('$TiO_2 (wt') + ')$')
```

Comment: @DYZ Using the %% works for me when printing, but for some reason it doesnt seems to work on plot labels

Comment: First, looks like the closing parenthesis is out of place. Shouldn't you have `'{0} %'.format('$TiO_2 (wt') + ')$\n'`? Second, I tried your expressions, and it correctly shows the % sign (so, I withdraw my first comment).

Comment: @DYZ yes, nevertheless the plot label still ends in TiO2 (wt     The only easy solution I found was definng variables such as                
a='$TiO_2 (wt$'

b='%'
c='$)$'

plt.ylabel(a+b+c), the problem with this is that the % sign is not 'scientificly' styled

Comment: So, what do you see instead of "%"? And what is the value of `'{0} %\n'.format('$TiO_2 (wt') + ')$'`?

Comment: I don't see anything, it just abruptly ends at TiO2 (wt      , the value of the `'{0} %\n'.format('$TiO_2 (wt') + ')$'`  is the string $TiO_2 (wt %  )$ (with the dollars signs and everything), nevertheless the closing parenthesis is printed on a second line in the label, I really dont now why

Comment: The % symbol can signify a placeholder for a value. Instead of enclosing the symbol in "" or '', have you tried """ """ (docstring format is printable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the closing paranthesis is on a new line is the use of `\n`. We might want to remove that and use a single string like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gcf()
plt.xlabel('$TiO_2 \, (wt\, \%)$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks I was breaking my head over this